# read raw output camera image incorrect

Tags: opencv, camera

I bought a raw data output camera sensor, it's data sheet in this website:
https://www.leopardimaging.com/uploads/LI-USB30-IMX225C_datasheet.pdf

it's resolution is 1312x992, 12 bits raw stream.

I have wrote a ISP program, it's input should be a raw picture, such as a.dng or b.raw and so on.Then i want to use this program and camera sensor to do preview.

simple code like this:

```
int main() {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat src;
    if (cap.isOpened()) {
    while (1) {
        cap.read(src);
        namedWindow("capture", 0);
        imshow("capture", src);

        waitKey(10);
    }
  }
}
```

there are some problem, color and resolution are incorrect.

first, color is green, it's abnormal.And it's resolution is 320x240.

Can anyone know why is this, and help me to fix it.

Thank you!

**Example image**

[image: screensaver]

Comment: In the PDF you have linked it shows a green image in the "RAW data streaming". If it is 12 bit stream, then the data should be parse accordingly (not done automatically by OpenCV). I mean, from this 12 bits how to change it to 24 bits for opencv to work correctly. About the resolution, some cameras can have more than 1 resolution settings, and this can be changed with [set](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) function of the videoCapture class

Comment: Actually, thinking it better, the resolution problem could also be influenced by the 12 bit part... OpenCV is expecting 24 bit images, and receives 12 bit per pixel, this means the resolution is double for the camera (your case 640 x 480).